# Jquery get the children with a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with `id='tips'`. It has a multiple childs. What I need to do Is I want to fetch a child of the div with `id='tips'` which has its style, top < 10px. Here's a snippet of the code.

```
<div id="tips">
   <div style="top: 5px; left: 150px;">
      Required Div
      <span class="arrow"></span>          
    </div>
   <div style="top: 15px; left: 150px;">
      Not-Required Div
      <span class="arrow"></span>          
    </div>
   <div style="top: 45px; left: 150px;">
      Child3
      <span class="arrow"></span>          
    </div>
</div>
```

> Only one div child div with top<10px exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `filter()`:

```
var $child = $("#tips div").filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).css("top"), 10) < 10;
});

// you can do as needed with the element(s) here, this is just an example
$child.css("color", "#C00");
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KHbLx/)

Comment: Wow you beat me by 10 seconds :). Also, it is good practice to always add radix to `parseInt`.

Comment: would this return only one child or multiple if there are multiple childs with top < 10 ?

Comment: @MarkoDumic Thanks - if I had a penny for every time I forget the radix, I'd be a rich man :)

Comment: @Rohan this would return all the children where top is < 10, there may be none, 1 or many.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan a little help over here please, I copied the same thing but I cannot get it to work. when I tried to log inside the .filter(function() { console.log('here');
} It is not executed. What could be the possible reasons for that ?

Comment: did you put the `console.log()` before the `return`? I've update my answer with a fiddle so you can see it working.

Comment: Ofcourse I did :). Yes and I saw the fiddle example thank you I'll try to figure out what might be going wrong.